# Send an authenticated POST request to tastypie

Tags: python, django, curl, tastypie

I am trying to send an ApiKey-autheticated POST request to a tastypie API

#### my Model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%self.name
```

#### my ModelResource

```
class ThingResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Thing.objects.all()
        resource_name="thing"
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

#### my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from tastypie.api import Api
from myapp.api import ThingResource

mobile_api = Api(api_name='mobile')
mobile_api.register(ThingResource())

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^api/', include(mobile_api.urls)),
)
```

#### and my cURL command

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d"username=vikingosegundo" -d"api_key=12345" -X POST --data "{\"name\":\"arrrg\"}" http://localhost:8000/api/mobile/thing/
```

#### the Response

```
{"error_message": "No JSON object could be decoded", 
 "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/resources.py\", line 178, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/resources.py\", line 379, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/resources.py\", line 409, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1077, in post_list\n    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/resources.py\", line 328, in deserialize\n    deserialized = self._meta.serializer.deserialize(data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/serializers.py\", line 161, in deserialize\n    deserialized = getattr(self, \"from_%s\" % desired_format)(content)\n\n  
    File \"/Users/vikingosegundo/Coding/Project/serverside/mysite/tastypie/serializers.py\", line 305, in from_json\n    return simplejson.loads(content)\n\n  
    File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py\", line 307, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n\n  
    File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py\", line 319, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n\n  
    File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py\", line 338, in raw_decode\n    raise ValueError(\"No JSON object could be decoded\")\n\n
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded\n"
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?** How do I point tastypie to the json object? The auth+auth seem to be working.

Comment: In your `curl` command, you have `-d"api_key=12345`. Where do you come up with the key of `12345`? Is that listed somewhere on your server? I'm struggling with knowing what the api_key is in order to make the GET request in the first place.

Comment: Not sure why you struggle with a question answered 3 years ago, but yes, api_key is listed on the server and is a API key.

Comment: I struggle with it because I'm only just starting to work with TastyPie as of last week. Despite the question being answered three years ago, it's new to me. Do you think my comment/question is unreasonable? Is it unheard of that someone who is just starting with TastyPie would not fully grasp certain aspects even though others have figured it out years ago?

Comment: You should clearly express, what you are struggling with, search for solutions and in case you can't find any, create a new question. comments on another persons questions aren't the right place to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `-d` and `--data` with curl is mangling the POSTed data.

Including the `username` and `api_key` params in the GET should solve this, like so:

```
    curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json"\
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST\
    --data "{\"name\":\"arrrg\"}"\
    "http://localhost:8000/api/mobile/thing/?username=vikingosegundo&api_key=12345"
```

Comment: Also, to use `curl` with Session authentication over HTTPS: `curl --dump-header - -H "Referer: https://website.com/"  -H "X-CSRFToken: uZX1OdFrIfu29XnpVwIBeGfKN2Ypg3PE"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"     -H "Cookie: csrftoken=uZX1OdFrIfu29XnpVwIBeGfKN2Ypg3PE; sessionid=2snb01a56oxdk9e902q0as8g5kj8wl9r"  -X POST  "https://server.com/api/mobile/thing/" --data '{"name": "arg"}'`

Answer (score 6):

I want to add an answer myself. Instead of Josh's solution I am not adding the credentials as  `GET`-parameters, but I transmit them as custom HTTP headers.

```
class CustomApiKeyAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        username =  request.META.get('HTTP_X_MYAPP_USERNAME')   or request.GET.get('username')
        api_key =   request.META.get('HTTP_X_MYAPP_APIKEY')     or request.GET.get('apikey')

        if not username or not api_key:
            return self._unauthorized()
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            return self._unauthorized()
        request.user = user
        return self.get_key(user, api_key)


class ThingResource(MopedModelResource):
    creator     = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'creator',    full = not True)
    class Meta:
        queryset        = Thing.objects.all()
        resource_name   = "thing"
        authentication  = CustomApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization   = ThingAuthorization()
```

Now we can add the `X-MYAPP-USERNAME` and `X-MYAPP-APIKEY` to the request.
Here a plain telnet session, using GET

```
GET /api/mobile/thing/ HTTP/1.1
X-MYAPP-APIKEY: 12345
X-MYAPP-USERNAME: vikingosegundo

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2011 19:37:05 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, …
```

and a session for POST:

```
POST /api/mobile/thing/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 49  
X-MYAPP-APIKEY: 12345
X-MYAPP-USERNAME: vikingosegundo

{"name":"qwerty","creator":"/api/mobile/user/1/"}
HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2011 20:12:32 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa:8000/api/mobile/thing/8/
```

And as we also check the GET-parameters in case no header is provided, this also works:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/mobile/thing/?username=vikingosegundo;apikey=12345;format=json
```